# Extract log data after particular date from log file

Tags: regex, powershell, text, replace

I have a problem with PowerShell regex. I have this input:

```
---
New command: 20. 12. 2017 00:01:19
End command: 20. 12. 2017 00:01:19
---

---
New command: 20. 12. 2017 00:06:19
Time 47 ms.
Deleted 18
Created 15
End command: 20. 12. 2017 00:06:19
---

---
New command: 20. 12. 2017 00:11:19
Time 47 ms.
End command: 20. 12. 2017 00:11:19
---

---
New command: 21. 12. 2017 00:16:19
Time 31 ms.
End command: 21. 12. 2017 00:16:19
---
```

I have following code but it doesn't work could you please tell me why?

```
$File = Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\processed.txt
$Result = $File -replace "([^/]+)End command: 20. 12. 2017 (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)","" > C:\Users\user\Desktop\processed.txt
```

The output should be only log with date 21. 12. 2017 and higher.

```
---
New command: 21. 12. 2017 00:16:19
Time 31 ms.
End command: 21. 12. 2017 00:16:19
---
```

Comment: How is it failing? What results are you getting that you didn't expect? What troubleshooting steps have you taken, with what result?

Comment: basically nothing happens, no error, I tried edit regex step by step but with no result

Comment: Describe in words what you think your regex does.

Comment: Your regex does something completely different than what your requirements are. You can do it with regex, but it won't be easy. You need a multiline regex, that matches both ´New command`, `End command` and everything in between. I would handle the lines in a loop instead with one or more internal regexes.

Comment: basically I need capture all text from the top until the "New command: 21. 12. 2017". I'm not sure but normal simple regex should be ok or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd split the log at information block boundaries:

```
$log  = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.log' | Out-String
$data = $log -split '(?<=---)\r?\n(?:\r?\n)+(?=---)'
```

Then I'd check each individual information block for the date:

```
$ref = (Get-Date '2017-12-21').Date
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$data | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '(?<=New command: )\d+\. \d+\. \d{4}' -and
    [DateTime]::ParseExact($matches[0], 'dd\. MM\. yyyy', $culture) -ge $ref
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you! Now I need to figure out how to replace the result in log file.

Answer (score 0):

Regex for date `21. 12. 2017` and higher.

**Regex**: `(?:(?:2[1-9]|3[0-1])\.\s12\.\s2017|(?:\d{2}\.\s){2}(?:201[8-9]|20[2-9][0-9]|[2-9][1-9][0-9]{2}))`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9k7iGf/1)